# PHP -- get array index where key DOES NOT equal "string"

Tags: php, arrays, string-formatting

So say I have an array that looks like this:

```
$format = [
  "client" => ["date" => "j F, Y", "time" => "g:i A"],
  "server" => ["date" => "Y-m-d",  "time" => "G:i:s"]
];
```

Given a String of either `"client"` or `"server"`, how would I select that index that does NOT equal the given string?

IE: if given `"client"`, I want to retrieve the `"server"` index. The array will always contain only those 2 primary keys (`client` and `server`).

I am aware this could easily be done in a if:

```
if($string == "client"){
   return $format['server'];
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this inline without the additional if statement.

I'm trying to do something with this:

```
$oldFormat = $format[provided string][$type];
$newFormat = $format[NOT provided string][$type];
```

Comment: this is programming language. You need to learn how to implement own logic.

Comment: If you don’t like an `if` statement, you could use the ternary operator instead, that’ll make it a little “shorter”. Apart from that I can’t think of anything (anything still sensible at least) – this is just not broad enough a use case to have something for that “built-in”.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: no need to be hostile. I fail to see how this question does not fit the scope of this site. I'm not asking someone to write an app for me, I already know a way to do it, I'm asking if there is a better way to do what I am trying. Quit being a grouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I could think of except constants:

```
$logic = [
    'client' => 'client',
    'not client' => 'server',
    'server' => 'server',    
    'not server' => 'client'
];

$oldFormat = $format[$logic['client']][$type];
$newFormat = $format[$logic['not client']][$type];
```

Constants would be:

```
define('client', 'client');
define('not_client', 'server');
define('server', 'server');
define('not_server', 'client');

$oldFormat = $format[client][$type];
$newFormat = $format[not_client][$type];
```

Comment: it's fun code but still, quite useless if you got 3 or more choices (mostly because "not xxxx" is ambiguous with more than 2 values)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an additional conversion-array is a possible solution:

```
$string = "server";
$type = "date";

$convert["client"] = "server";
$convert["server"] = "client";

echo $format[$convert[$string]][$type]; // gives you the date-format of the client
```

Anyways not shure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing code [*golf*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) then the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) is a suitable one-liner that is notably still **readable** at a glance... think about the next poor sod that has to maintain your code after yourself!

```php
$newFormat = $format['client'==$string ? 'server' : 'client'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun I can add another solution:

```
$format[current(array_diff(array_keys($format), array($input)))]
```